# Jquery - Slide Menu (HandMade)

Tags: jquery, html, css

How are you people?, im doing a script for a slidemenu using ul/li(ul/li), the idea is to be using slideup/down without inner classes

The trouble i have is when click in a link inside my ul (father) li (son) ul li a the son´s  ul (ul li ul) get hide. The idea it´s just to make that if you click in the ul li a, not in the ul li ul li a. I tried with ":first", ".first()", ":first-child".

Hope could make myself clear. :D

here´s the code:

HTML

```
    <ul id="menu"> 
       <li> 
           <a href="#">Menu 1</a> 
           <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
           <a href="#">Menu 2</a> 
           <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
```

Javascript (Jquery)

```
    function submenu(id) { 
       var div = "#"+id; 
       $("ul"+div+" li a").each(function () { 
          $(this).click(function() { 
             var li = $(this).parent();       
             $("ul"+div+" li ul").each(function () {   $(this).slideUp("fast");   }); 
             if(li.children("ul").is(":visible")) {  
                li.children("ul").slideUp("fast"); 
             } else {  
                li.children("ul").slideDown("fast");  
             } 
             return false; 
          }); 
       }); 
    } 

    $(document).ready(function(){   submenu("menu");   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

either use the child css selector ('ul.' + div + '> li > a) or select the children with jQuery.

```
$(div).children(li).children(a).each(function() {
  /* your code here */
});
```

As you have it, your first selector is grabbing all the anchors in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't konw if I've really understood your problem, but here is a jsfiddle in action : 
http://jsfiddle.net/BVVGX/

If you click on a child, nothing happens, but if you click on a father, it slides up or down its own children.

**Edit :** http://jsfiddle.net/BVVGX/6/

The key is to add a callback after the slideDown in order to hide the others already opened menu as during the slideDown Jquery doesn't really know if the `ul` is visible or not.

Comment: you got it right, but had an issue. when you click in another link (that has sub menu) doesn´t hide the previously opened. That´s the big deal of my script :(